# How to disable dialog box after closing it once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is use case:

User is prompted a dialog box if user responds to that dialog box , then that dialog box should not appear to user again.
this can be done by removing the dialog box like `$("#dialog-box").remove()`
But the problem is on refresh that dialog box will appear again.

My guess for solution ( not sure if this is possible):

when user responds to dialogbox, create some kind of global variable like `SHOW='true'`, when page is refreshed see if `SHOW` is `true` then remove the dialogbox from DOM.

Any ideas on this are welcomed.

**Solution**

Using the cookie approach something like:

when cookie value with name `"dialogbox"` doesnt exist, then create cookie giving value as `"foo"`. 
if cookie's value is `"foo"`, then only show the dialogbox.
And when user responds to dialogbox, then change the value of that cookie to`"bar"`.
Since the cookie value is not `"foo"`, then dialogbox will not appear.

found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) useful.

Thanks for your answers and comments.

Comment: Have you considered `cookies` or `localStorage`?

Comment: You can also store theh value in cookie and second time user visit the site before open dialog box check if value exit in cookie or not.

Comment: You could use cookies or localStorage to keep information about whether the dialog box was displayed or not.

Comment: Do you have control of the backend?

Comment: A cookie will persist across page refreshes.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions for this, first one is to use a server-side validation. Where as you have said, to create a variable and if HTML has to show the dialog then it must show, otherwise the HTML would not even pass the dialog box down to the user.

Otherwise, save it as a cache object to the user's browser. This way jQuery or JavaScript would handle it and show/not-show the dialoug to the user.

Answer (score 0):

All global variables are restored each time when the page is refreshed. To store state between page reloads you have to use some persistent storage (cookies, local storage on client side) or (session, database) on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set a cookie when its shown first time and before showing the box check if the cookie is set. If cookie is set remove or dont show the box. If cookie is not set show it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that you can do it with global variable, because on refresh it will be restored.

If you want to do it with javascript/jQuery only, I will suggest adding some parameter to the url on accept and check for its presence in your code.

Otherwise use session, cookies or some sort of storage.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have suggested, there are multiple ways to implement the behaviour. Below is the Cookie-approach.

When the dialog is closed, add a cookie:

```
document.cookie="dialogShown=1; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2014 12:00:00 UTC; path=/"; // this cookie will expire on 18th of Dec this year
```

**Now, make the dialog box as initially hidden** and only displayed after the DOM is loaded and the cookie does not exist:

```
// From: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
} 

function cookieExists(name) {
    return getCookie(name) != "";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if(!cookieExists("dialogShown")) {
        $("#dialog-box").show()
    }
});
```